# Usage of CASE Statements in WHERE Clause - PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested, conditional-statements, case

Can someone tell me what is the use of last 'Y' in the " **end = 'Y')** "

```
( case
 when a = 'STAGE PAYMENT' then
 'Y'
 when b not IN ('To be Received', 'Received') then
 'N'
 when c != (d - NVL(e, 0) - NVL(f, 0) - NVL(g, 0)) then
 'Y'
 when NVL(h, 0) + NVL(i, 0) + NVL(j, 0) <> 0 then
    case 
    when c != k then
    'Y'
    when (-l != NVL(e, 0) + NVL(f, 0) + NVL(g, 0) + NVL(m, 0)) then
    'Y' 
    else 'N'
    end 
 else 'N'
 end = 'Y')
```

Also, is there any way of optimizing this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the context of this case statement? It looks like it may be a part of a `where` clause?

Comment: Yes, it's a part of a select query and this is just after the where clause.

Comment: looks like the statement `end = 'Y')` should end as `end) = 'Y'`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the outer brackets are completely unnecessary, so it doesn't matter if the closing bracket goes after or before the `= 'Y'`

Comment: whatever... yes, might be considered by both sides @Boneist

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan what might be considered by both sides? I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I meant both way is possible with or without parentheses, depending on what OP presented, I considered parentheses @Boneist

Comment: That’s actually Oracle SQL, not PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last `end = 'Y')` is nothing but the comparision.

Your case statement is generating one value based on condition and if it is `Y` then that condition will be statisfied and row will be considered in the result.

Lets say, If `a = 'STAGE PAYMENT'` is true for some record then your `case` statement will generate `Y` as output, which will be again compared with last `end = 'Y')` and returns true.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!! :)

Answer (score 0):

As your case statement is part of the `where` clause, that `= 'Y'` is there to form the predicate.

Predicates most often have the form of `<some value> <comparison operator> <other value>` (there are exceptions, most notably `regexp_like`), where the `<some value>` and `<other value>` can be columns, functions, literal values, expressions, variables, etc.

Your `case` expression is simply taking up the place of the `<some value>`, i.e.:

```
select ...
from   ...
where  <some_col> = 1
and    case .... end = 'Y'
```